# How to write correctly a for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am facing some issues with for loop in Python. The correct result is on the left, mine is on the right: [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRdLW.jpg)

```
rows = 9
    for row in range(1, rows+1):
        a = 1
        for j in range(rows, 0, -1):
            if j > row:
                print(' ', end='')
            else:
                print(a, end='')
                a += 1
        print('')
```

The bottom part suppose to be on the right side (mirrored from the top one), but with that code it stays right under the top part without being moved to the right:

```
for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    rows -= 1
    for j in reversed(range(1, i + 1)):
        print(j, end='')
    print('')
```

So, any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can move the bottom part to the right?

Comment: Don't overthink this. Just print some spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to print the left-trailing spaces in your second pyramid!

adding:

```py
print(' ' * 9, end='')
```

here:

```py
rows = 9
for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    rows -= 1
    print(' ' * 9, end='')
    for j in reversed(range(1, i + 1)):
        print(j, end='')
    print('')
```

does it.

Comment: tijmenvanetten, thanks a lot, that worked!